# Errors during flutter tool build on macOS

Tags: flutter

**Environment**

- macOS Sierra 10.12.5
- flutter alpha 0.0.31 - framework revision d36e2f6191

**Scenario**

When installing Flutter on macOS, I have following errors.

```
$ git clone -b alpha https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
$ export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
$ flutter doctor
Downloading Dart SDK 1.24.0-dev.6.7...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 57.9M  100 57.9M    0     0  10.8M      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 12.0M

Building flutter tool...
Failed to precompile coverage:run_and_collect:
'package:convert/src/hex/encoder.dart': malformed type: line 20 pos 13: cannot resolve class 'ChunkedConverter' from 'HexEncoder'
    extends ChunkedConverter<List<int>, String, List<int>, String> {
            ^
Failed to precompile archive:tar:
'package:convert/src/hex/decoder.dart': malformed type: line 21 pos 13: cannot resolve class 'ChunkedConverter' from 'HexDecoder'
    extends ChunkedConverter<String, List<int>, String, List<int>> {
            ^
Failed to precompile coverage:collect_coverage:
'package:convert/src/hex/decoder.dart': malformed type: line 21 pos 13: cannot resolve class 'ChunkedConverter' from 'HexDecoder'
    extends ChunkedConverter<String, List<int>, String, List<int>> {
            ^
Failed to precompile coverage:format_coverage:
'package:convert/src/hex/encoder.dart': malformed type: line 20 pos 13: cannot resolve class 'ChunkedConverter' from 'HexEncoder'
    extends ChunkedConverter<List<int>, String, List<int>, String> {
            ^
'package:convert/src/hex/encoder.dart': malformed type: line 20 pos 13: cannot resolve class 'ChunkedConverter' from 'HexEncoder'
    extends ChunkedConverter<List<int>, String, List<int>, String> {
            ^
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue on my local machine.

convert-2.0.1 package was incorrect on my pub-cache.
See following diffs.

```
$ /usr/bin/diff -r pub.dartlang.org.bak/convert-2.0.1 pub.dartlang.org/convert-2.0.1/
diff -r pub.dartlang.org.bak/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/hex/decoder.dart pub.dartlang.org/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/hex/decoder.dart
20,21c20
< class HexDecoder
<     extends ChunkedConverter<String, List<int>, String, List<int>> {
---
> class HexDecoder extends Converter<String, List<int>> {
diff -r pub.dartlang.org.bak/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/hex/encoder.dart pub.dartlang.org/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/hex/encoder.dart
19,20c19
< class HexEncoder
<     extends ChunkedConverter<List<int>, String, List<int>, String> {
---
> class HexEncoder extends Converter<List<int>, String> {
diff -r pub.dartlang.org.bak/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/percent/decoder.dart pub.dartlang.org/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/percent/decoder.dart
28,29c28
< class PercentDecoder
<     extends ChunkedConverter<String, List<int>, String, List<int>> {
---
> class PercentDecoder extends Converter<String, List<int>> {
diff -r pub.dartlang.org.bak/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/percent/encoder.dart pub.dartlang.org/convert-2.0.1/lib/src/percent/encoder.dart
22,23c22
< class PercentEncoder
<     extends ChunkedConverter<List<int>, String, List<int>, String> {
---
> class PercentEncoder extends Converter<List<int>, String> {
70a70
>         (byte >= $0 && byte <= $9) ||
```